# Why nothing comes up in VS Code when I do a git commit command in GitBash?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am using GitBash to do a git commit command on a Windows machine
I have already set VS code as the default editor with:
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"

Steps:

1. Edited a file in my repository
2. Entered git add . (it recognizes the change I made and adds it
3. Entered git commit

VS code opens up correctly on my machine, but no file comes up for me to enter the commit message

Has anyone had this happen to them? This is the first time doing a commit from git bash to do the message in VS code.

Help: About
Version: 1.84.2 (system setup) Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z Electron: 25.9.2 ElectronBuildId: 24603566 Chromium: 114.0.5735.289 Node.js: 18.15.0 V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0 OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

Comment: Welcome! 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) backup your user settings.json file and then temporarily reset it to default (delete its contents) to see if this happens with default settings. 3) try adding the `--disable-extensions` flag to the command and see if that changes anything.

Comment: 1)
Version: 1.84.2 (system setup)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
2)Tried that and still happened
3)Git Bash did not recognize the --disable-extensions command

Thanks!

Comment: `--disable-extensions` is a VS Code flag- not a Git Bash flag. also, I bolded "into your question post".

Comment: Thanks! The --disable-extensions in VS code did the trick.

Comment: okay, well, that's great, but let's actually find out which extension is the problem. disable all your extensions globally, and then enable them one by one and test after adding each one to see which one makes it stop working.